# States are not getting updated within map functions

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I am trying to update a state inside the map.on('click') function, but it's not getting updated, and it is still frozen with the initial value when console.log(geoJson), the result is always the initial value

```
const [geojson, setGeoJson] = useState<any>({
  features: [],
  type: "FeatureCollection",
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (drawingMap.current) {
    return;
  } // initialize map only once

  drawingMap.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
....
  });

  drawingMap.current.on("click", (e: any) => {


    const feature = {
      geometry: {
        coordinates: [-66.324462, -16.024695],
        type: "Point",
      },
      properties: {
        iconSize: [60, 60],
        message: "Foo",
      },
      type: "Feature",
    };

    console.log(geojson);

    setGeoJson((prevState: any) => ({
      ...prevState,
      features: [...prevState.features, feature],
    }));
  });
});
```

I've tried implementing another useEffect with drawingMap and geojson in the dependency array, but the function is getting executed 3-5 times on each click, but the state is changing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell without seeing how you initialize your map, but I suspect you need to call the `GeoJSON` instance's `setData` method with your new features, [documented here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/sources/#geojsonsource#setdata). Your `useEffect` runs on every render (including state updates), but you return early from the effect after the first effect completes, so new maps with updated features are never initialized.

If you'd prefer a more declarative model, [React Map GL](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) provides a nice wrapper around Map GL JS. Their site has some [useful examples](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/examples/draw-polygon) which show how user interaction with the map might work.